# Flymake configuration error while programming in C

Tags: c, emacs

When trying to run M-x Flymake-Mode in Emacs I get:

```
Flymake: Configuration error has occured while running (make -s -C ./CHK_SOURCES=helloworld_flymake.c SYNTAX_CHECK_MODE=1 check-syntax). Flymake will be switched OFF
```

I am invoking the command in a buffer called helloworld.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

And have a file called Makefile in the same directory:

```
helloworld: helloworld.c
 gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.0.91.1 under Ubuntu 9.04.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19):

`Makefile' must contain the`check-syntax' target. Append this to the Makefile:

```
check-syntax:
     gcc -o nul -S ${CHK_SOURCES}
```

Make sure you use a TAB to start the second line. Also there is a bug with flymake that makes you have to name the Makefile with a capital M. It won't work if you, say, call it "makefile." Watch out for that!

Comment: The problem with this method is gcc will not allow it to work if  has more then one file. Anyway to get around this?
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.

Comment: One line: `check-syntax:; g++ -o nul -S ${CHK_SOURCES} --std=c++14; rm nul`

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual content of your makefile? It looks like there is a space ' ' before the second line. This is supposed to be a tab:

```
helloworld: helloworld.c
 gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

More like this:

```
helloworld: helloworld.c
    gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

Keeping in mind, that the SO editor seems to have converted my tab character to spaces, so don't do that.

```
helloworld: helloworld.c
<press tab here>gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a tab, not a space. It compiles fine when I type "make" at the shell.